# graph-tool - AttributeError: 'PropertyDict' object has no attribute 'species'

Tags: python-2.7, graph-tool

I have the following code to annotate a graph using property maps:

```
from graph_tool.all import *

# define graph
g = Graph()
g.set_directed(True)
species = g.new_vertex_property("string")
species_dict = {}
reaction_dict = {}

#add species and reactions
s1 = g.add_vertex()
species[s1] = 'limonene'
species_dict[g.vertex_index[s1]] = 'limonene'

g.vertex_properties["species"] = species
g.vp.species[s1]
```

When I run this I obtain the following error message:

```
File "/home/pmj27/projects/NOC/exergy/make_graph.py", line 45, in <module>
g.vp.species[s1]

AttributeError: 'PropertyDict' object has no attribute 'species'
```

Why is this? If I type `g.vp` into my IPython console I get `{'species': <PropertyMap object with key type 'Vertex' and value type 'string', for Graph 0x7f285d90ea10, at 0x7f285d90ef90>}` as answer, so there clearly is a property map.

Comment: Did you mean `g.vp['species'][s1]`?

Comment: No, that returns `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Really?! That's certainly syntactically valid Python.

Comment: graph-tool defines its own classes, presumably they have a different syntax?

Comment: They are free to implement their own methods (e.g. `__getitem__` and `__getattr__` for `thing[item]` and `thing.attr`, respectively), but it would be unusual to throw a `SyntaxError` in those cases.

Comment: What version of graph-tool are you using?

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: `print graph_tool.__version__`

Comment: `2.2.42 (commit 35e808bd, Tue Apr 21 21:09:55 2015 +0300)`

Comment: This version is too old to support the attribute syntax. I have added an answer pointing this out below. BTW: The name of the library is graph-tool, not "graph tools".

Comment: Thanks. I haven't gotten around to testing it yet due to some IT issues yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The access to property maps via attributes (as `g.vp.species[s1]` in your example) is only available in more recent versions of graph-tool (currently 2.11, as of Nov 2015). In the version you are using (2.2.42), you must use the dictionary interface: `g.vp["species"][s1]`.